# How to bootstrap dropdown button with click function in knockout

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, knockout.js

i have a button dropdown with options and it works as i want, but i need to remove te input circle image in options, is it possible?

or any other idea? thanks!

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Menu 2</button> 
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item"><input type="radio" name="options" value="type1"  autocomplete="off" data-bind="checked: type"> option 1 </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item"><input type="radio" name="options" value="type2"  autocomplete="off" data-bind="checked: type"> option 2 </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css rule :

```
input[type="radio"] {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```